# To evaluate $\sin(55°)$ with $10^{-4}$ error margin, how many terms are needed for the Taylor Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

To evaluate $\sin(55°)$ with $10^{-4}$ error margin, how many terms are needed for the Taylor Series that is at point of $a={\pi\over 3}=60°$ of $\operatorname{f}(x)=\sin x$?

## Hi! This is the question above. And below is what I have managed to do, so far! Can you check if it is correct and if not, can you show me the correct one?
$$\operatorname{f}(x)=\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

## $$\sin x=\lvert\frac{\operatorname{f}^n(60°)}{n!}(x-60)^n\rvert\space\space\space\space\space x=55$$

$$n=0\Rightarrow\frac{\operatorname{f}(60°)}{0!}={{\sqrt{3}}\over {a}}$$
...
$$n=10\Rightarrow\lvert{\operatorname{f}^{10}(60°)\over 10!}(-5)^{10}\rvert\not\lt 10^{-4}$$
...
$$n=15\Rightarrow\lvert{\operatorname{f}^{15}(60°)\over 15!}(-5)^{15}\rvert =0.011668\not\lt 10^{-4}$$
...
$$n=18\Rightarrow\lvert{\operatorname{f}^{18}(60°)\over 18!}(-5)^{18}\rvert =0.0005\not\lt 10^{-4}$$
...
$$n=19\Rightarrow\lvert{\operatorname{f}^{19}(60°)\over 19!}(-5)^{19}\rvert =0.00007\lt 10^{-4}$$
...
$$|Error|=\lvert S-S_n\rvert\leq\lvert S_{n+1}-S_n\rvert = a_{n+1}=19$$
$$a_n=18$$

Comment: The Taylor series you quote expects $x$ to be measured in radians, not degrees.  The difference from $60^\circ$ is $\frac {5\pi}{180}\approx 0.087$.  You will need many fewer terms.

Comment: OK, it should be measured in radians but what do you mean by "less than 1" term? I couldn't understand you actually

Comment: The Taylor series that you quote, $f(x)=\sin x=\ldots$, is the expansion around $0$. You are asked to use the expansion around $\pi/3$, which is different. And when you do, $x$ becomes $\pi/36$, which converges very fast.

Comment: I have revised the comment.  $1$ radian is about $57^\circ$, so $55^\circ$ is just less than $1$ radian.  I hadn't noticed the Taylor series was centered at $60^\circ.$

Comment: If $x = \pi\cdot 55/180$, I get $\sin(x)\approx 0.81915204428899178968$ and $x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040} \approx 0.81915015296619535624$.  The difference is about $-1.891\cdot 10^{-6}$.

Comment: So... what I understand is... what I have done above is actually correct but I just need to write ${\pi\over 3}-{\pi\over 36}$ instead of $60^∘$?